# $a>0$ and $X$ is a random variable that $X \le a$ Prove $ P\{X \ge 0\} \ge \frac{1}{a}E(X)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, markov-process

it is similar to Markov's inequality.

I try to prove it by an example from the book:
An urn contains balls numbered $1$ to $N$. Let $X$ be the largest number drawn in $n$ drawing when random sampling with replacement is used. The event $X \le k$ means that each of $n$ numbers drawn is less than or equal to $k$ and therefore $P\{X \le k\}={\big(\frac{k}{N}\big)}^{n}$

but I did not understand how to relate it.

When I try to relate it to Markov's inequality:

If $X$ is a non-negative random variable and $a > 0$, then the probability that $X$ is greater than $a$ is less than the expectation of $X$ divided by $a$.

In my case,  $a > 0$

How do I progress?

Answer (score 0):

$1_{X\geq 0}$ is the characteristic function of ${\mathbb R}^{+}$ applied to $X$ and $1_{X< 0}$ is the characteristic function of ${\mathbb R}^{-}$ applied to $X$.
$$
E(X)=E(X1_{X<0})+E(X1_{X\geq0})\leq E(X1_{X\geq0})
$$ Because $E(X1_{X<0})<0$

But $X\leq a$, so:

$$
X1_{X\geq0}\leq a1_{X\geq0}
$$

Hence:

$$
E(X1_{X\geq0})\leq E(a1_{X\geq0})=aE(1_{X\geq0})=aP(X\geq 0)
$$

Thus:

$$
E(X)\leq aP(X\geq 0)
$$

In case you don't know:

$$
1_{X\geq 0}=\begin{cases} 1 \quad if\quad X\geq 0 \\ 0 \quad if\quad X<0\end{cases}
$$

Comment: If someone knows how to write the characteristic function of a set in Latex, please edit my answer.

Comment: I don't understand the relation to Indicator function
Can you expand your explanation ?

Thanks.

Comment: @Asaf what steps seem to be unclear to you? The first line was just decomposing the mean, into positive and negative.